# SQL How to include and exclude NULL values in where clause

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a `@AgentGroup` parameter in my SSRS that uses a SP.

What I want to do is if the parameter passes a value `PREPB_STRSTR,NULL` it will also display the null values. I thought about adding a `OR @AgentGroup is null` in my where clause but what if the parameter only passes a value `PREPB_STRSTR` it will also display the null data.

```
DECLARE @DateTo date = '3/21/2017',
@DateFrom date = '3/21/2017',
@VHGroup nvarchar(max) = 'PREPB_STRSTR,NULL'


  SELECT 
  [AgentIRACGroup]
  ,[CallOutCallID]
  ,[CallOutDateTime]
  ,[OutboundDuration]
  ,[CallOutNumber]
  ,[AgentName]
  ,[CallOutAgentID]
  ,[AgentGroup]
  ,[Outcome]
  ,[TalkTime]
   FROM [AgentStatisticsEOD].[dbo].[IRAC_Data]
   WHERE CONVERT(Date,[SCBCallDateTimeRequest]) BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo 
   AND [AgentGroup] collate database_default in (SELECT value from dbo.FnSplit(@VHGroup,',')) OR [AgentGroup] is null
```

My query will always display the null `[AgentGroup]` even the `@Agentgroup` does not passes null values.

Comment: Isn't it just an issue with the higher precedence of AND w.r.t. OR? I mean don't you want `AND ([AgentGroup] ... OR [AgentGroup] is null)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to solve it is to add another condition to check if the parameter actually contains the word `NULL`:

```
DECLARE @DateTo date = '3/21/2017',
@DateFrom date = '3/21/2017',
@VHGroup nvarchar(max) = 'PREPB_STRSTR,NULL'


SELECT 
[AgentIRACGroup]
,[CallOutCallID]
,[CallOutDateTime]
,[OutboundDuration]
,[CallOutNumber]
,[AgentName]
,[CallOutAgentID]
,[AgentGroup]
,[Outcome]
,[TalkTime]
 FROM [AgentStatisticsEOD].[dbo].[IRAC_Data]
 WHERE CONVERT(Date,[SCBCallDateTimeRequest]) BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo 
 AND [AgentGroup] collate database_default in (SELECT value from dbo.Split(@VHGroup,',')) 
 OR 
 (',' + @VHGroup +',' LIKE '%,NULL,%' 
  AND [AgentGroup] is null
 )
```

Comment: can you explain this broadly?

Comment: What part did you not understand? It's basically the same query as the one on the question, the only difference is that `[AgentGroup] is null` will only effect the results if `@VHGroup` contains the word `NULL`.